# Including setup.py in the wheel

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

The `setup.py` has the wheel version in it, and we would like to include it in the wheel to avoid need to type in new versions in multiple files in the project - e.g. in a `version.py` or `__init__.py` somewhere else.

In the `setup.py` the following directive is included

```
    package_data={
        'ddex.resources': ['schema-validation-rules.yaml'],
        '': ['setup.py'],
    }
```

The first one for the *schema-validation-rules.yaml* *does* show up properly in the wheel under *ddex.resources*  . The *setup.py* does not get included. Why is that and how can it be included?

**Update** It appears to be relevant to mention that this wheel is getting loaded into *Azure Synapse* spark pool.

Comment: What if 2 libraries do the same? Which `setup.py` will prevail in `site-packages`? -- I think it is a bad idea, I very much recommend against this. There are already a bunch of ways to "single source" the version string, all with their pros and cons, but this one is probably one of the less good ones I have seen so far.

Comment: If you use `package_dir`, you can maybe make it so that `setup.py` ends up inside the import package, which would be acceptable. Or maybe you can customize setuptools command. But that does not seem worth the cost. Use something like `setuptools-scm` to take care of that. But my preferred solution is to not do anything, and then use `importlib.metadata.version('NameOfLibrary')` to obtain the version string of any installed library.

Comment: There is a bunch of solutions [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/), version 5 is the one I recommend, nowadays you can probably target Python 3.8+ only and simplify by using `importlib.metadata` only. -- This the solution I personally use in my own projects: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/project_version.html

Answer (score 2):

> need to type in new versions in multiple files in the project -

The latest Python versions can directly read the installed package versions. You do not need to manually maintain `VERSION` variable or similar.

Python code:

```py
from importlib.metadata import version
my_version = version("my_package")
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#overview).

Comment: will try that immediately

Comment: "importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for my_package"

Comment: You need to first install your code as a package, or properly set up local development package.

Comment: The wheel is not going to be installed via pip, but only used within spark packages . What can we depend on here?

Comment: I don't know what is Spark and it is not mentioned in your question, so I cannot help you. Please open a new question if Spark does not support the Python standard method of getting the package version.